# PDO not inserting more than one row in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I'm having trouble inserting image data into my database. I have a table called `images`. When dumped with PHPMyAdmin it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `images` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orig_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(12) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `uploaded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `views` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `album_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `server_id` (`server_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This is the code I'm using to insert rows:

```
// Database connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb', 'root', '');                  

// some code...

$st = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `images` (orig_name, hash, filename, uploaded, server_id)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT `id` FROM `servers` WHERE `name` = ?))');
$st->execute(array($origName, $fileHash, $filename, date('c'), $server));

// more code...

// Database cleanup
$st = null;
$db = null;
```

The script returns no errors, and works flawlessly for the first row inserted. If the script runs again, it fails to insert any more rows in the `images` table. I see no reason why it'd behave like this, the data going into each field is unique each time (except for the server_id field).

Comment: Do you need to set `id` to auto_increment, or does it do that automatically if it's a primary key?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `id` is set to auto increment.

Comment: Not in your posted table definition, it is not. `PRIMARY KEY` does not imply `AUTO_INCREMENT`, as primary keys are not necessarily integers at all.

Comment: Damn it, I distinctly remember setting it as AI when I set up the table. Dunno how it changed. :/ But that's the problem, thanks.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't seem to have any error checking in there, so it's not going to be returning errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` field isn't set to auto_increment.

The first record that you post will be added, with a NULL as `id`; the second record won't be added because there's already a record with NULL as the primary key, so it'll fail - you don't have any error checking in the code, so it won't be printing out the errors it's getting back.